# What's the difference between 'configure' and 'configureGlobal' methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm playing around with Spring Security configuration and find out, that the most common way to configure in-memory authentication is using `configureGlobal()` method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("userPwd").roles("USER");
  }
}
```

But there is another way, which is less widely used, overriding `configure()` method from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication(
        .withUser("user").password("userPwd").roles("USER");
  }
}
```

I'm just wondering, what's the difference between them and what's the point of usage `configureGlobal()` method over `configure()` one?

Answer (score 3):

This answer helped me.

[Difference between registerGlobal(), configure(), configureGlobal(),configureGlobalSecurity in Spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218354/difference-between-registerglobal-configure-configureglobal-configureglo)

If you already extend class like `WebMvcConfiguratorAdapter`, you have two choices for security settings.

1. Using `configureGlobal()` method:

   - Single `@Configuration` class approach.
   - You can set security while maintaining your config class.
   - SpringWebConfig extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` + `@EnableWebSecurity`
2. Overriding `configure()` method:

   - Specific security `@Configuration` class.
   - You must create a new config class to extend `WebSecurityConfiguratorAdapter` for security setup.
   - `MySecurityConfig` extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Answer (score 2):

As the [spring security doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration) says:

> The name of the `configureGlobal` method is not important. However, it
>   is important to only configure `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` in a class
>   annotated with either `@EnableWebSecurity`, `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`,
>   or `@EnableGlobalAuthentication`. Doing otherwise has unpredictable
>   results.